# php unable to connect to memcached at times when under high load

Tags: php, load, connection, memcached

I'm having a very frustrating problem I cannot figure out.

I have a website that spikes in traffic once a week.  It runs on PHP using memcached to cache certain data.  When it spikes, I see memcache getting 600+ req/s.  This is when the problems happen.  Every now and then it throws a message telling me the PHP is unable to connect to memcache.  This causes my page to show random blank pages.

I would also like to point out that memcache isn't using much space.  Only about 30MB.  I have a situation where PHP accesses the same cache object many times.  I also noticed that is the same object in cache is accessed many times, it loads slightly slower than another object that isn't accesses so often.

Other notes: I host mysql, memcache, php-fpm, and nginx on the same box.  The server doesn't seem to be under high load becaus it uses about 20-35% of the CPU and has a loadavg < 6, and there is plenty of free memory.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thats only a rough assumption due to very sparse information from your site. But sounds somehow as you would  hit the `maximum number of open files`. Or some different limitation of the same kind.

Shows you the parameters on your box(hard and softlimit of maximum of open files)

```
ulimit -Hn
ulimit -Sn
```

Another option is that you didnt configure the maximum number of parallel requests properly in memcached configuration.

memcached help:

```
-c       max simultaneous connections (default: 1024)
```

Comment: The results:

ulimit -Hn : 1024
ulimit -Sn : 1024

memcached -c is set to 10000, so I don't think the problem is there.  Also, if this were a file descriptor limit, where would it log such errors so I can check to confirm that it is indeed this type of error. Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: The position in your log depends on your linux distribution as well as your settings. But most likely `/var/log/messages` will hold informations. You may use `lsof -p <pid>`. But with this setting 10000 parallel connections will not be possible.

Comment: I run Ubuntu 10.04 64bit.  I see a bunch of errors like this in /var/log/messages.

Jul 20 13:47:18 server1 kernel: [864540.650111] __ratelimit: 247 callbacks suppressed
Jul 20 13:47:18 server1 kernel: [864540.650115] php5-fpm[16194] general protection ip:6b7123 sp:7ffff65a6aa0 error:0 in php5-fpm[400000+717000]

I edited nginx and php5-fpm to change the rlimit from 1024 to 8192, but I still see the same error happening.

Comment: I have also changed the hard/soft ulimit to 8192 using ulimit -n 8192 command.  I will keep an eye on the logs and respond back if this error happens again. Thanks again.

Comment: sounds like a segfault error happening between php and the kernel. There was some time ago a post on the nginx mailing list http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,86831

Comment: I think you're right. I may have the same problem as in my php-fpm log I am getting some segfault errors. Would you be able to comment on this?  The mailing list does not provide a solution.

Comment: Another thing is that you need to set these limits not only with ulimit there is a configuration file under `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Comment: For the segfault i think there is no general solution maybe try to build your php5 and fpm manually on a newer version but no guarantee that it will work

Comment: Hey I think I found the problem and solved it.  I did a lot of digging into the segfault issue here on SO and found out that the opt cacher I am using (APC) has a bug in it that may be the cause of these errors.  So I temporarily disabled APC and everything worked just fine.  No segfaults and it always connects to memcached now.  The CPU load went up by an additional 10%, but at least there are no problems. We learn something new every day.  Thanks again for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

What architecture are you using? CentOS? In version 6, there are some changes to the `/etc/security/limits.conf` (a file `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf` overrides these with a max of 1024 files by default). You'll need to create a new file like `/etc/security/limits.d/99-memcache.conf' with something like:

```
* soft nofile 4096
* hard nofile 10240
```

Since files in this `limits.d` folder are processed alphabetically, this will override the 1024 limit, but not cause problems the next time you do a major OS update.